# Unable to upgrade pulseaudio on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, upgrade, permissions, pulseaudio

I'm unable to upgrade pulseaudio on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  pulseaudio
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.    
2 not fully installed or removed.  
Need to get 0 B/766 kB of archives.  
After this operation, 4,096 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 341675 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.8) over (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7)...  
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pulseaudio_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb (unpack):  
unable to create '/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/hdmi-output-1.conf.dpkg-new'  
(while processing '/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/hdmi-output-1.conf'):  
Permission denied  
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...  
Errors were encountered while processing:    
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pulseaudio_1%3a8.0-0ubuntu3.8_amd64.deb  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is the output from `sudo apt-cache policy pulseaudio`

```
pulseaudio:
  Installed: 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7
  Candidate: 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.8
  Version table:
     1:8.0-0ubuntu3.8 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.7 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:8.0-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Here is the output from `ls -ld /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  6 10:58 /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes, I did an upgrade that was how the whole thing started. I have also tried to run `sudo apt-get -f install` and I got the same error.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Here is the output from `ls -ld /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/hdmi-output-1.conf*`  `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 161 Nov 15 16:19 /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/hdmi-output-1.conf`

Comment: @DavidFoerster I performed the upgrade as usual by running `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks. Now you just need to add all that you your question. ;-) In any case it's weird that the package post-installation script doesn't have permission to access those files. Can you please perform a simple access test and [edit] your question to include the output of `cd /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths && sudo touch hdmi-output-1.conf foobar.15132; rm -f foobar.15132`. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you, I have found the cause of the issue. The directory `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths` was set to immutable (don't know how and why). So I changed it by running `sudo chattr -Ri /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths`. And everything was fixed.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths` was set as immutable. I changed it by running `sudo chattr -Ri /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths`. And Everything was fixed.